# mongoose sort date doesn't sort correctly

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting, date, mongoose

I'm trying to sort event docs by date, so that "nearest" future event is first and the "furthest" away event will come last.

**My schema**

```
// Event Schema
const EventSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    dateStart: {
        type: Date
    },
    dateEnd: {
        type: Date
    },
    bsShiftType: {
        type: String
    },
    adminID: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
});
```

**My get method + sorting attempt**

```
const d = new Date()
const today = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth()-1, d.getDate()-1,23,59);

module.exports.getRequestEvents = function (parentID, callback) {
const query = {
    parentID: parentID,
    dateStart: {
        $gte: today
    }
};
Event.find(query).sort({ dateStart: -1 }).limit(1000).exec(callback);
```

}

**Result**
as you can see they are not sorted correctly. the days looks fine the are increasing, but the hours is the opposite, they are descending. Why?

```
0:{_id: "5a80e1ff4e93820834ee8db5", dateStart: "2018-02-13T23:00:00.000Z",…}
1:{_id: "5a809e0a0fed7c34043af6f1", dateStart: "2018-02-11T02:00:00.000Z",…}
2:{_id: "5a809e230fed7c34043af6f3", dateStart: "2018-02-11T01:00:00.000Z",…}
3:{_id: "5a809e1e0fed7c34043af6f2", dateStart: "2018-02-11T00:00:00.000Z",…}
4:{_id: "5a809fa082e6e113e41e483c", dateStart: "2018-02-11T00:00:00.000Z",…}
5:{_id: "5a809f8c82e6e113e41e483a", dateStart: "2018-02-11T00:00:00.000Z",…}
6:{_id: "5a809f9b82e6e113e41e483b", dateStart: "2018-02-11T00:00:00.000Z",…}
7:{_id: "5a809d560fed7c34043af6f0", dateStart: "2018-02-10T23:00:00.000Z",…}
8:{_id: "5a80e1cf4e93820834ee8db2", dateStart: "2018-01-12T23:00:00.000Z",…}
9:{_id: "5a80e1d74e93820834ee8db3", dateStart: "2018-01-11T23:00:00.000Z",…}
```

The order i'm trying to achieve is:
11th 00:00, 11 01:00th........, 14th 02:00, 14th 06:00

Comment: The field in db looks like `dateStart` and in query you are using `startDate`

Comment: Thanks. that was part of the problem! i whish it would have thrown an error on sort on non existing property... Now i at least got the days sorting correctly, but the hours are wrong. I updated the question with the new results

Comment: Because `dateStart: -1` means descending, `dateStart: 1` is ascending

Comment: Yes, im aware. and i'm trying to make the "total date" descending.... the days are returned in correct order all the 11th's first and the two 14th's as last. the they are soreted reversed by the hours. 3,2,1,0....
You see? days 11,11,11....,14,14 but the hours are sorted opposite

Comment: Your actual output doesn't reflect your sort condition. Not sure what "total date" descending means. Did you mean ascending ? but anyways your output is not ordered in any particular order. You've have 11's first followed by 10 and 14.

Comment: 10T23 is tecnically 11 when you do .getDate() ?
 however.... if descending means newest first, and ascending means oldest first? then i think i need descending right? all my dates are "in the future" the oldest of them must be the one closet to "now"

Comment: _10T23 is tecnically 11 when you do .getDate() ?_ No. So as I understand you want the future dates closest to now. So in your case it should be for now (assume `2018-02-10T00:00:00.000Z`) will be 10th-23:00, 11th-00:00, 11th-01:00 ...14th-02:00, 14th-06:00. Are you sure you have correct filter ? I don't see any filter that limits to only look for document with dates greater than now

Comment: So i added a date filter, for greater than today. As i expected it didn't change anything about how the dates are sorted. I updated the result, and the order looks like a mess. Any idea on what is causing this behavior ?

Comment: Today in your case is `"2018-01-10T23:59:00"` in your local time zone. So the order looks good to me.  You just need { dateStart: 1 } to get the expected output. What is wrong ?

Comment: oh my... you are right... how did i not notice.

Comment: I'm having same issue when using `{ timestamps: true }` mongoose will add `createdAt` and `updatedAt` but how do I sort by them?